# Python Math Problem My result is so close to example but bot same

Tags: python

According to the x value entered using the formula below
Write the code of the program that calculates the value of y.

```
           1
    ---------------
            1
    x + ----------
              1
       x + ------
             1
        x + ---
             2
```

For example:

```
If x = 1, y = 0.6000000000000001
If x = 10 y = 0.09901951266867294
If x = 100 y = 0.009999000199950014
If x = -5 y = -0.19258202567760344
```

My code

```
x = float(input("x= "))
y = (1.0/(x+(1.0/(x+(1.0/(x+0.5))))))
print(y)
```

My result

```
x= 1 y= 0.625
x= 10 y= 0.09901914992993928
x= 100 y= 0.009999000199462694
x= -5 y= -0.19262295081967212
```

I don't know where i did wrong. Results are so close.

Comment: Don't post photo. Put it as text.

Answer (score 2):

That's because not every number can be represented as floating-point. For example, 0.2 in decimal has finite numbers of digits, but in binary it has not (like 1/3 in decimal). To make very precise operations on floating-point variables, you can use decimal floating point, which works more like a decimal than binary.

Floating-point error:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation

Decimal floating-point:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point
https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1):

in python the interpreter takes approximate for large numbers in (1/1.5) gives out 0.6666666... so add 1 and dividing 1 by it gives 0.6 then after adding 1 then dividing 1 by 1.6 aproximates to 0.625